# COUNTIF with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2007, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

Can you please advise on how can I use COUNTIF with multiple conditions?

[image]

My proposal (left) shows the formula for one criterion (distinct regions).

However, I am interested in counting distinct regions for each distinct month (two criteria) - on the right: desired result.

Answer (score 12):

you can use `COUNTIFS()` instead

```
=1/COUNTIFS($A:$A,A2,$B:$B,B2)
```