# Count of distinct values, based on a second parameter

Tags: excel

Say I have column A as Number, and B as Type:

[image]

I want to count how many unique numbers there are for Type "C" and Type "I" respectively. In the example, the results I'd want are "C": `2`, "I": `3`.

How can I do a count of distinct values, based on a second parameter in Excel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [countif - multiple criteria - Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215915/countif-multiple-criteria-excel)

Answer (score 1):

Easy with a PivotTable (Excel 2013 and later):

[image: SO33218415 example]